# Why is a function parameter considered an undefined variable?

Tags: matlab

I've been looking around for a while, but I can't seem to find something that describes and answers the problem I've been having.  Namely, I have a function being defined in a `ball` class that checks to see if it and another ball are intersecting (due to the balls being kept on the same z-plane and the radius being the same for all of them, I've simplified the problem to that of intersecting circles).  This function is as follows (where both `obj` and `other` are of the class `ball`, and where the `ball` class contains a position vector of length 3):

```
function intersected = ball_intersection(obj, other)
    intersected = (obj.position(1)-other.position(1))^2+(obj.position(2)-other.position(2))^2 <= (2*ball.radius)^2;
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable other.

Error in ball/ball_intersection (line 29)
            intersected = (obj.position(1)-other.position(1))^2+(obj.position(2)-other.position(2))^2 <= (2*ball.radius)^2;

Error in ball/move (line 56)
                if ball_intersection(other)

Error in finalproject (line 41)
    cueball.move(0.0001, 0, 0, 9.32, 4.65, otherball);
```

For some reason, Matlab thinks that a function parameter is undefined, and I don't know how to make it know that it is in fact defined right there.

Any and all help is appreciated - thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ball_intersection` has to be called with two input arguments.

Most likely, you want to change line 56 of `ball` to `if ball_intersection(obj,other)`, or `if obj.ball_intersection(other)`.

Comment: Taking your first suggestion worked, I presume the second would as well.  In many other languages, member functions can be called without having to explicitly mention the caller - I guess not in Matlab.