# What is the source of an apparent argument mismatch in a while loop?

Tags: matlab

This is from the same project as [Why is a function parameter considered an undefined variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288588/why-is-a-function-parameter-considered-an-undefined-variable).  In this case, I have a vector of `ball`s from which I am acquiring a velocity vector (of length 3) whose values I am squaring and then summing.  For some reason, it thinks that the following code results in a comma separated list that does not have just one value, where if I run each bit piecemeal, it works just fine.

```
>> while sum(balls.velocity.^2) ~= 0
end
 comma separated list must have exactly one item.

>> sum(balls.velocity.^2) ~= 0

ans =

     1

>> while ans
end
>> %had to CTRL+C in order to exit the infinite loop
```

How do I make the while loop understand that it is only receiving one value?

Comment: what is balls.velocity? How is it defined? I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Daniel `ball` is an object that I created, `balls` is a vector (currently of length 2) of them, `velocity` is an attribute of the `ball` class.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but this code allows to reproduce the problem: `balls(1).velocity=[1,2,3];balls(2).velocity=[1,2,3];`

Comment: That essentially represents the situation.  Do you not understand what I'm asking (in which case I can clarify), or do you not (hopefully yet) have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why, but this solves the issue:

```
while sum([balls.velocity].^2) ~= 0,end
```

Comment: That does the trick!  

For some reason, when the .^ operation is applied to balls.velocity by itself and when surrounded by the sum method, it works, but when the sum method is removed, I get the following error: 
>> balls.velocity.^2
Error using  .^ 
Too many input arguments.
Which makes me think that this was the root error that somehow finally came to light when put in a while loop.  When balls.velocity is surrounded by the braces, it puts all of the values into a single vector, which then works with no problems.

Comment: Also, is there no way for a new line character to be added into a comment?  When I'm in the editing window for my comment, it all looks nice, but when I submitted it, all of the new lines went away :(